# MVC + WCF + TDD or DDD architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, tdd, domain-driven-design

Here we are again at the crossroads.

i want to try to implement, at least for the next 3 years, a simple, proven way to architect my applications. 
Every time i am going to start a project it feels like it's the first time because of the overwhelming number of "ways" to  create websites these days.

i have this sample code i got from this package i purchased call Design Pattern Framework 4 C#. Among the multiple projects they have, there is one, which is called, Design Patterns in Action. You can download it from here https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=B853B0DB724C30E5!16735&authkey=!AOeHSAWa_P4vzzU

My question, after you take a look at that solution, What's good, bad, what would you keep, what would you remove, what's unnecessary, etc etc. about this example?

I understand they are trying to show multiple clients and also multiple DAOs. But overall, would this architecture be one that you would take as a "template"?
Thanks.

Comment: The only answers you can possibly get to this will be of the form, "I think XYZ is good because I use it"

Comment: There is no magic bullet, one size fits all cure. You use whatever makes you the most productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question, after you take a look at that solution, What's good, bad,
>   what would you keep, what would you remove, what's unnecessary, etc
>   etc. about this example?

After a quick look, here's what I'd say :

- With regards to the DDD tag on your question, this is clearly not a domain driven architecture. The business objects look [anemic](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) apart from a few simple validation rules and many of the basic building blocks of a DDD architecture aren't present (aggregates, value objects, etc.)
- Unless I have missed something, most business operations are CRUD operations which is not really representative of a real-world enterprise app.
- There's a fat Service layer with a fat ActionService class which basically seems to handle all the use cases of the application. The good news is, it deals with the uses cases in an agnostic way (as far as I can tell, the Request and Response objects it manipulates are delivery mechanism independent). Being fat is less desireable, as the class includes too many responsibilities ([SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).
- Using Repositories on the client side and DAOs on the server side seems weird, but why not.
- If it's really test-driven, why not include all unit tests instead of just one sample ?

Apart from that, the layers are well designed and, as the multiple presentation layers show, it shouldn't be difficult to substitute one front-end for another or one persistent store for another.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not a "full application. I think they wanted to show pretty much how different patterns work together, etc. After reading a little bit about DDD i realized it has nothing to do with DDD.

I think the reason they have repositories on the client is to be able to unitest it. That's what the documentation says. As a matter of fact, this sample comes with a windows form sample as well, wpf, webforms (mvp). but i deleted it because it was irrelevant to my question. As a matter of fact, the MVC project is the only one using a repository to access the service.

Comment: I guess this sample would be better to use with a lightweight app that is not going to grow. Something quick. Agree?

Comment: Lightweight is not necessarily how I'd describe it. You can feel that the architecture was designed to be modular and quite a lot of layers of abstraction were added to make that modularity possible. Like I said, you could swap one peripheral layer for another quite easily, which isn't the case with lightweight apps where the UI basically talks to the database directly.

Comment: Well, in my best effort, i try to never mix responsibilities no matter how small of big the project is. I try to keep UI separated. So my "business objects", data access, etc. Using business logic in the OnClick event of a button has been abandoned about a decade ago :). I see your point thou. I still can't grasp the whole DDD concept. They always talk about COMPLEX apps. What makes an app complex or not? That's a very blurry line... anyway. I am going to try to use this sample the best way possible and try to learn DDD the best i can. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

System Architecture is much like building architecture:

- There is not one "right" way
- Everyone has their own opinions on the "best"
- The "best" architecture depends on the context and needs
- Styles and methods change over time

There are many factors that go into choosing an architecture:

- Time to Market - how long do you have to get something going?
- Maintainability - will you be the only one maintaining it?  Open Source?
- Extensibility - will it be a closed or open system?
- Scalability - simple utility or enterprise-scale?
- Platform - web or native?  Desktop or Mobile?

All that to say I'd be surprised if you could come up with one all-emcompassing framework that fits every project you're going to have for the next 3 years.  Think of MVC, WFC, TDD, DDD, etc. as **tools** that you can use to build <strike>the **right**</strike> a system that meets the needs of that situation.

My opinion is: use whatever concepts you can understand (and can teach others if necessary) as long as it fits the particular situation.

Comment: even better with system architecture in that we can go in and change our buildings : )

Comment: I understand your point. I am trying to have a balance between all the elements involved in a web application. i guess what confuses me most is the overwhelming number of "best practices" you find out there. Reality is that many times they contradict themselves. I am trying to use the above solution to set myself a "working template" since all my apps are pretty much structured the same way. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As @d_stanley says, MVC, WCF, TDD and DDD are tools, frameworks, methodologies, a collection of best practices, etc.  TDD has zealotry that would cripple a project if you followed it to-the-letter, DDD like Design Patterns is a toolkit you can pick and choose from (you shouldn't try to use it all in every project).  MVC and WCF are funky frameworks to make it easier to create/handle websites and communications respectively and would be good choices all round.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose one.
2. Try it out.
3. Refactor/change if its not right for you.

Most importantly make sure you use patterns that are refactorable. If you are using TDD and find you can inject your dependencies, fakes, etc then this will ease the refactoring process. Three years is a long time to use any given pattern. A friend said if you dont look at code from 6 months back and think it sucks, well you may not be learning enough : )

Comment: You're totally right about looking at code that is six months old. That's exactly what i am trying to do: Not to get trapped in the "perfectionist" side of coding. I found this piece of code, seems very robust, also a little bit generic, but at least it gives you an idea of one of many ways to do things "correctly".